# Смена временной зоны php

Tags: php, timezone, временная-зона

Подскажите в чем дело. Пытаюсь изменить временную зону вот так:

```
// ставлю разные значения от 1 до 12
// как минус, так и плюс
date_default_timezone_set('UTC+1');
echo '<b>', date_default_timezone_get(), '</b>';
```

Мне всегда выводится: **`Europe/Moscow`**

Из-за чего это происходит? Возможна ли смена зоны, без использования:
`Europe/Amsterdam`, `Europe/Kiev`, `Europe/Chisinau`, `Europe/Samara` ... ?

Comment: А если без изменения php.ini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нашел в списке поддерживаемых параметров `'UTC+1'`

[http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Так должно работать:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+1')
```

**UPD:**
Сразу не увидел, в конце мануала написано :

Пожалуйста, не используйте описанные здесь временные зоны (кроме UTC), они существуют только по причинам обратной совместимости.

Comment: Более того, надо проверять результат выполнения функции. "Функция возвращает FALSE, если timezone_identifier имеет неверное значение, в остальных случаях TRUE"

Comment: Работает, благодарю!